# changing store on internal pages give 404 in magento

Tags: magento

changing store on internal pages give 404 in magento. like if I am on a category page of english store -  http://luxecoat.nextmp.net/english/men/leathers.html

and now when i  change  the  store  it gives me  404 error.

Comment: Ok, a 404 means Resource Not Found, so the route to that page is not established. Has it worked before? In order to help, you'll have to post code and maybe a directory structure of the pages you are referencing.

Comment: have checked your logs?